# DataFrame Slice Assignment inconsistency

Tags: python, pandas

Why does

```
df = pd.DataFrame({1 : np.random.randn(5),
                  2 : np.random.randn(5),
                  3 : np.random.randn(5)}, index=[1, 1, 2, 2, 2])

a = np.array([3.1, 3.14, 3.1415])
df.loc[2, 2] = a
```

Work but

```
df = pd.DataFrame({1 : np.random.randn(5),
                      2 : np.random.randn(5),
                      3 : np.random.randn(5)}, index=[1, 2, 1, 2, 2])

a = np.array([3.1, 3.14, 3.1415])
df.loc[2, 2] = a
```

not? As you can tell, the only difference is the index.

Comment: Both work for me. What error do you get?

Comment: I am getting 'ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable' for the second one. This problem literally confused me for a good thirty minutes.

Comment: Must be being generated on data different from that presented here. Maybe the number of IDs being assigned is different from the size of the array you're assigning?